# finds all possible permutations of a certain numbers of distinct digits

Tags: algorithms

I am stuck on the following problem. I want to find an algorithm that finds all possible permutations of a certain numbers of distinct digits and then put them in a large matrix for instance. For instance for the digits 0, 1 and 2 I want to get the matrix:

2 1 2 0 1 0
1 2 0 2 0 1
0 0 1 1 2 2

Here they are in order but this is not required per se. Does anyone know a nice algorithm to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most languages have libraries that can do permutations for you - [perl](http://search.cpan.org/~allenday/Math-Combinatorics-0.09/lib/Math/Combinatorics.pm) [python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) [ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation) [java](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html) - don't do work that is already done for you.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [MichaelT's comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194863/finds-all-possible-permutations-of-a-certain-numbers-of-distinct-digits#comment376874_194863), here's an example solution in Python:

```py
from itertools import permutations
for p in permutations(['0', '1', '2'], 3):
    print p
```

Output looks like this:

```
('0', '1', '2')
('0', '2', '1')
('1', '0', '2')
('1', '2', '0')
('2', '0', '1')
('2', '1', '0')
```

You'll have to arrange the output to match your desired format.